# Silex autoload psr-4 class does not exist

Tags: php, autoload, silex, psr-4

I have this error:

> InvalidArgumentException in ControllerResolver.php line 147: 
>   Class "MyProject\API\FrontController" does not exist.

Here is my structure of myproject:

- composer.json
- api

  - src

    - FrontController.php
    - BundlesFolders
  - app
  - web
- vendor
- clients

My composer.json

```
"psr-4": {
        "MyProject\\API\\": "myproject/api/src",
        "MyProject\\Client\\": "myproject/client/src"
 }
```

My routing.php :

```
// myproject/api/app/config/routing.php
$routes->get('/', 'MyProject\API\FrontController::exec')
```

FrontController.php :

```
<?php 
// myproject/api/src/FrontController
namespace MyProject\API; 
class FrontController {
```

Comment: Did you remember to `require` `vendor/autoload.php` in routing.php?

Comment: Yes vendor/autoload.php is here, before the `$app = new Application()` and I tried `composer dumpautoload -o` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put an extra folder to your psr-4 map. The first *myproject* directory should not be in your path as this path is relative to the composer.json file and your src code is in api/src and clients/src (the second is just a guess, you didn't post the content of the clients directory).

Let me tell you that IMHO your directory layout is weird. I would have a single `src` directory and inside put an api and a client subdirectory.

PS: You've listed the client directory in singular but in composer you have it in plural, watch out for this details!

Also run `composer dump-autolad` after changing your psr-4 parameter.